# Akka.net actor can't handle low latency messages?

Tags: akka.net

I have this work-flow:

1. A method inside parent

   ```
           Receive<UpdatePositionCmd>(cmd =>
       {                
           cmd.Qty = 150;
           cmd.Price = 100;
           _positionCoordinatorActor.Tell(cmd);

           Thread.Sleep(30);

           cmd.Qty = 250;
           cmd.Price = 200;
           _positionCoordinatorActor.Tell(cmd);

           Thread.Sleep(30);

           cmd.Qty = 133;
           cmd.Price = 300;
           _positionCoordinatorActor.Tell(cmd);
       });
   ```
2. Method inside the position Coordinator which receives messages from #1, finds appropriate child and forwards the message:

   ```
           Command<UpdatePositionCmd>(cmd =>
       {
           var child = LookupChild(cmd.PositionName);
           if (child != ActorRefs.Nobody)
           {
               child.Tell(cmd);
           }
           else
           {
               var @event = new PositionUpdatedEvent(cmd);

               Persist(@event, positionUpdatedEvent =>
               {
                   var childActor = Context.ActorOf(Props.Create(() => new PositionActor()), cmd.PositionName);
                   childActor.Tell(cmd);
               });
           }
       });
   ```
3. Method inside a child which gets the forwarded message:

   ```
           Command<UpdatePositionCmd>(cmd =>
       {
           Console.Write($"\nCmd Qty: {cmd.Qty}");
           Qty += cmd.Qty;
       });
   ```

So my question: with the `Thread.Sleep(30)` between "Tells" I get correct output:

Cmd Qty: 150 
Cmd Qty: 250 
Cmd Qty: 133 
Total Qty: 533

But should I remove or decrease the `Thread.Sleep(30)` I am getting this messed up results where basically it only reads the last message but three times:

Cmd Qty: 133 
Cmd Qty: 133 
Cmd Qty: 133 
Total Qty: 399

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A method inside parent` receives an `UpdatePositionCmd` instance, passes it on to the coordinator, and then *updates this very same command*. With the delay this is less obvious because the command is issued the second time after processing of the first has completed.

You should create a new instance for each call to `_positionCoordinatorActor.Tell` and make the `UpdatePositionCmd` immutable so you don't inadvertently change an instance that's sent away already.